# why i get result DeferredCoroutine{Active}@6c629d6e & DeferredCoroutine{Active}@5ecddf8f when I need result Counting

Tags: kotlin, async-await, kotlin-coroutines, coroutinescope

I've below code blocks:

```
// TODO 1

import kotlinx.coroutines.*


suspend fun sum(valueA: Int, valueB: Int): Int {

   delay(3000L)
   return valueA + valueB
}

// TODO 2

suspend fun multiple(valueA: Int, valueB: Int): Int {
   delay(2000L)
   return valueA * valueB
}
```

Main:

```
fun main() = runBlocking {

    println("Counting...")

    val resultSum = async {sum(10, 10) }
    val resultMultiple = async { multiple(20, 20) }

    // TODO 3

    println("Result sum: $resultSum")
    println("Result multiple: $resultMultiple")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`async` function [returns](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/coroutines/coroutines-basic-jvm.html#async-returning-a-value-from-a-coroutine) a [`Deferred<T>`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-deferred/index.html) object. It has [`await`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-deferred/await.html) method to wait for result:

```
println("Result sum: ${resultSum.await()}")
println("Result multiple: ${resultMultiple.await()}")
```